# Convert base64 html image to an image to show on Flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm having this data url from an nft image: `data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB3aWR0...`

How can i decode it to an image to show on flutter app with Image.memory. I tried base64.decode but it returns 'Invalid image data'. I think because this url returns an html instead of an image?

Answer (score 2):

This is an SVG image. You can use this library:
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';

String decoded = utf8.decode(base64.decode(base64String));

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: SvgPicture.string(decoded)
      ),
    );
 }
```

Comment: base64decode returns Uint8List and when i tried to parse it to string svg package throws invalid svg data

Comment: I tried something new, i take the decoded data and decode again with utf8, it returns raw svg string, parse it into svgPicture.string() but got a weird error Invalid double
50%.

Comment: @Long it works with simple SVGs. I assume it doesn't work because of the animations. See https://github.com/dnfield/flutter_svg/issues/772

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Basically currently there's no way i can show an animated html svg in flutter app.

Comment: I tried remove the % and the animation in the svg raw html, it rendered